# Update all rows in table with a value based on that row?

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I want to quickly update a table to get rid of any real data that got pulled down to a test server.

```
UPDATE users SET email = CONCAT ("fake", users.id, "@mycompany.org")
```

Is anything like that possible or will I need to write a script?

Comment: If this works than this Q looks rly silly dooesn't it :p  When I started writing the question my idea was for an auto-incrementing number, then realized I could use ids for a similar effect.

Comment: You could also just reconfigure your outgoing email server to rewrite all email addresses to yours.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the query you are using will work. That is, for a row like:

```
id = 21
name = 'sth'
email = NULL
```

It'll update and set the email to:

```
'fake21@mycompany.org'
```

And similarly for all the rows in the entire table.